# How to go to mysql database host on Linux CLI in RedHat 8

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat

I installed mariadb using

```
# yum install mariadb mariadb-sever
```

Then on running:

```
 # systemctl start mariadb
```

I got:

```
 # Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found
```

& on running:

```
 # systemctl restart mysqld
```

I got:

```
 # Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply **install**, activate at boot + start mysql executable :

```sh
yum install mariadb mariadb-server
systemctl enable --now mariadb.service
```

Comment: I installed MariaDB. After that I enter 'mysql -uroot -p' & enter password. Then that I get an error that says ERROR 2002(HY000): Can't Connect to local MySQL sever through socket 'var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: You need to specify `-h hostname` can be `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`

Comment: On entering 'mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p' I get error:"ERROR 2002(HY000): Can't Connect to local MySQL sever on '127.0.0.1' (115) " & same previous error when using  'mysql -h localhost -u root -p'

Comment: What is the output of `lsof -p :3306` ? (as root) Add it to your original post, not in comments

Comment: WARNING:can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs Output information may be incomplete

Comment: And the output of `netstat -nptl | grep :3306`

Comment: I am not getting any output on that

Comment: OK, so mariadb/mysql have to be started: `systemctl start mariadb`

Comment: I got error  " Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found"

Comment: Try this : `systemclt restart mysqld`

Comment: On trying "systemctl restart mysqld" I get: "Failed to restart mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found"

Comment: Try this : `systemctl restart mysql`

Comment: If not working, what is the output of : `systemctl list-units | grep -E '(mysql|mariadb)'`

Comment: It's okay: It worked on systemctl start mariadb.service

Comment: But using this I enter MariaDB database instead of MySQL, can I continue in this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
yum install mariadb mariadb-server
```

mariadb-server package contains the server daemon
mariadb package contains the CLI client

Comment: I installed MariaDB.After that I entered 'mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p' I get error:"ERROR 2002(HY000): Can't Connect to local MySQL sever on '127.0.0.1' (115) " & same previous error when using 'mysql -h localhost -u root -p'

Comment: Did you `systemctl start mariadb`? I think you need to spend 30 seconds googling how to get started with MySQL / MariaDB.